# C fgets_line of arbitrary length

Tags: c

This is meant to be a drop in replacement for getline as it's not crossplatform.
I am trying to do as minimal work as possible in here including only calling strlen once at the very end to calculate the size of the final block.

returns -1 for error, 0 for EOF, 1 for success

The way it works it by setting the last two bytes in the array as `[0, 1]` and if the buffer is filled it will look like `[X,0]`, `X` being either `LF` where we are done, or something else meaning we need to realloc and loop again unless we are at eof.

```c
int
fgets_line(char **line, size_t *capacity, size_t *length, FILE *stream) {
  if (!*line && !(*line = malloc(*capacity = 64)))
    return *capacity = 0, -1;
  (*line)[0] = 0;
  if (length)
    *length = 0;
  char *position = *line;
  while (1) {
    (*line)[*capacity - 1] = 1;
    (*line)[*capacity - 2] = 0;
    if (fgets(position, *line + *capacity - position, stream)) {
      if ((*line)[*capacity - 1] == 0
       && (*line)[*capacity - 2] != '\n') {
        size_t new_capacity = *capacity * 2;
        char *tmp = realloc(*line, new_capacity);
        if (tmp) {
          position = tmp + *capacity - 1;
          *line = tmp;
          *capacity = new_capacity;
        } else return -1;
      } else goto success;
    } else if (position != *line) {
      if (feof(stream))
        goto success;
      return -1;
    } else return 0;
  }
  success:
  if (length)
    *length = position - *line + strlen(position);
  return 1;
}
```

usage is similar to getline

```c
int main() {
  char *line = NULL;
  size_t capacity = 0, length = 0;
  int result = 0;
  while ((result = fgets_line(&line, &capacity, &length, stdin)))
    printf("---Capacity: %-8zuLength: %-8zu---\n%s------\n", capacity, length, line);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

- Do not put the sentinel characters in every iteration. Set them before the loop, and after a successful reallocation.

  Also, `(*line)[*capacity - 2] = 0;` is redundant. Indeed, if `(*line)[*capacity - 1]` remains `1` we don't care, and if it turns to `0` then `(*line)[*capacity - 2]` has been overwritten anyway.
- `goto` is totally unwarranted. `break` works very well.
- Do not handle `fgets` failures inside the loop. Break immediately.
- Using `position` as an index, rather than the pointer, seems cleaner. Consider

  ```
    fgets(*line + position, *capacity - position, stream)
  ```

  etc.

Answer (score 2):

**Error: Mishandles input errors**

When `fgets()` returns `NULL` due to an input error, this function might return 0 (for end-of-file).

**Lack of in code documentation**

A *declaration* like `int fgets_line(char **line, size_t *capacity, size_t *length, FILE *stream);` deserves documentation describing the goals and function  limitations.  (e.g. a .h file.) Do not assume users want to dissect the function source code to learn basic functionality.

**Minimum work**

"minimal work as possible" --> User I/O is a sink-hole of time. A linear extra call to `strlen()` will not be noticed.

**Pedantic: Reliance on not reading a *null character***

Code performs incorrectly with `*length = position - *line + strlen(position);` should `fgets()` read a *null character*.

Either adjust code to detect reading a *null character* (not easy) or consider dropping the `length` parameter.  Calling code can use `strlen()` if desired.

**Pedantic: `*capacity` not validated**

If `fgets_line()` is called with a wee `*capacity` (like 0 or 1), `(*line)[various]` risks accessing the array out of bounds.  Take care in assuming how  the caller set up the buffer pointer and size.  It may have been *right-sized* after a prior read.

**Pedantic: Out of `int` range**

`fgets()` uses an `int` for the size, so `*line + *capacity - position` risks out-of-range conversion.

---

**Design**

I am not a fan of giving the user the ability to overwhelm memory resources and prefer a sane upper bound to allocation size.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that fgets skips over NULL bytes, that hadn't even occurred to me. This function is supposed to return 0 for EOF, but I guess a valid point could be made that 0 should be success, -1 for EOF, and 1 for error. I did notice the out of int range problem when compiling with MSVC, and planned to solve it.

Comment: @Anotra `fgets()` does not skip over _null characters_.  It reads and saves them like any other non-`'\n'` character.  The trouble is that it is hard to detect them for the caller.

Comment: right, my wording was bad. That's what I mean